# Firebase domain <projectname>.firebaseapp.com works while <projectname>.web.app does not

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

After successful deploy, only one domain **(projectname).firebaseapp.com** works.
The **(projectname).web.app** shows Firebase message "Site Not Found - Why am I seeing this? ..." 
The index.html does not have any Firebase App setup

.

The Firebase console>hosting>dashboard shows two domains as default and no status:

**(projectname) domains**

| Domain | Status |
| --- | --- |
| (projectname).web.app Default |  |
| (projectname).firebaseapp.com Default |  |

How to make the shorter domain **.web.app** work? 
Does Firebase allow only one domain? 
If above is the case, how to select the domain? 
How to remove **.firebaseapp.com** while keeping **.web.app** 
Why two domains are listed as *default* ?

Answer (score 0):

Both names should work and serve exactly the same content.

It could be that something internally went wrong during the deploy, so trying running `firebase deploy` again to rule that out.

If the problem persists, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.